# Rename reconstructred object key to other name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
this.state = {
  date: {
    value: {
      from: '1/1/2019',
      to: '4/1/2019'
    }
  }
}

render() {
  const { date } = this.state

  return <Date date={date.value} />
}
```

I have to pass my state object into a component, I dislike date.value because it literally means date, but how to rename date.value to `date`?

I can deconstruct the value like so

```
render() {
  const { date: value } = this.state

  return <Date date={value} />
}
```

but if I have another component then it would not be great.

Comment: do you want remove value property and set it to date. Like `this.state = {
  date: {
      from: '1/1/2019',
      to: '4/1/2019'
  }
}`

Comment: why not directly change the data structure of your `state`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could destructure `value` and rename it to `date`.

```
render() {
    const { date: { value: date } } = this.state

    return <Date date={date} />
}
```

```js
var state = { date: { value: { from: '1/1/2019', to: '4/1/2019' } } },
    { date: { value: date } } = state;

console.log(date);
```

Comment: does this generate a name shadowing warning for `date`?

Comment: Wouldn't this make `date.date`?

Comment: @JackBashford, it does not change `this`.

Comment: @codekaizer, why should it? `date` is not used here, as i see.